# text is being changed when i do copy it from searchable pdf file (created with tesseract command) and paste it in notepad

Tags: pdf, cmd, ocr, tesseract, urdu

I have created a searchable pdf file by running following command on one of my images.

```
tesseract page.jpg test pdf --oem 1 --psm 5 -l urd
```

this the image which I have converted to searchable pdf.
[image]

the image contains Urdu text, but when I am copying it from newly created pdf file and pasting it in any other text editor, this is what I am getting.

> GehbFie”

any tesseract OCR and encoding expert here who can solve my issue please, any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried LibreOffice Writer, Microsoft WordPad, or Microsoft Word?

Comment: of course, I tried a lot of different editors (sublime, notepad, notepadd++, ms word, WordPad) but the result is the same in every editor, I think there is the encoding problem.

Comment: Very good brother I am happy you are trying to OCR Urdu. Waht is your progress ? Have you tried Google Vision API OCR ( Urdu included ) . https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pdf is the config file name. it needs to come last in the command, after --oem --psm -l etc.

the correct format for the command is following.

```
tesseract page.jpg test --oem 1 --psm 5 -l urd pdf
```

I resolved my issue in this way.

Comment: بہت اعلیٰ بھائی بہت خوشی ہوئی سن کر ۔ ابھی اس کام میں آپ کو کہاں تک کامیابی ہوئی ہے ۔ میں گوگل  کی ویژن او سی آر استعمال کر رہا ہوں بہت اعلیٰ ہے ۔ اس جیسی کوئی اور او سی آر اردو کے لیے میں نے نہیں دیکھی ۔ آپ کا تجربہ کیسے ہے ضرور شیئر کریں جزاک اللہ